# I'm Trying to get a button to link to a specified script

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, button

I have been given a script and some code.

It creates a floating button on my website in the bottom right corner.  I am trying to get the result of clicking that button, when you click a different button.  Meaning I want to access the content of that button through a button of my own that I can place where I want to place it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.levitate = {
    app_id: '5a621753acffbb001290f098',
    hash: '511d3530a3884e648c703e2c76b46fb3'
};
</script>
<script src="https://l3vitate.herokuapp.com/static/scripts/levitate-iframe.js"></script>
```

You can see here what the button does as is from placement of the script. www.exclusivecreationsdesign.com
button says "Free Quote" Green Button in lower righthand corner of page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.levitate = {
    app_id: '5a621753acffbb001290f098',
    hash: '511d3530a3884e648c703e2c76b46fb3'
};
</script>
<script src="https://l3vitate.herokuapp.com/static/scripts/levitate-iframe.js"></script>
```

I can create a button on my site, place it in-line with text and get the same pop-up as clicking the button it places in lower right hand corner of page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `document.querySelector('.levitateLauncherOpen').click()` and bind it to the `onClick` of your custom button.

Comment: Man, I really appreciate that, but it almost rhymed with Chinese to me.  LOL, I am a novice, extremely when it comes to code, php, etc.  Would you be so kind to elaborate?  Very much appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: I went to your website to see what the generated button looks like and checked the HTML source to see if it had any ids or classes assigned to it. Then it's just a matter of using the corresponding CSS selector as a parameter to the `document.querySelector` to fetch the actual element and then to trigger a `click()` on it.

Comment: Okay thank you.  So is this process done by locating the CSS Selector, which I've done and if I'm right it is: .Levitate-Frame.  and then I'm stuck.  LOL.  is this something that is written in the php file?  Or something that I would write into the code of the button?  Is their anything you can recommend I read to learn what you are explaining too me?  Can you give me a sample of this maybe?  I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Just put it into the a `onClick` attribute of your button. Assuming you want to use a span to define the button: `<span onClick="document.querySelector('.levitateLauncherOpen').click()">Click me</span>` and it should work.
This is rather basic HTML and JavaScript so maybe try looking for tutorials in those areas.

Comment: OKAY, THATS GREAT, I APPRECIATE IT.  That works, but how would you suggest I add that action to the following code?                                                                 [fusion_button link="" color="custom" size="large" type="" shape="square" target="_self" title="" gradient_colors="#bfe8da" gradient_hover_colors="#bfe8da" accent_color="#777" accent_hover_color="#777" bevel_color="" border_width="1px" shadow="" icon="" icon_divider="yes" icon_position="left" modal="" animation_type="0" animation_direction="down" animation_speed="0.1" class="" id=""]QUOTE GENERATOR[/fusion_button]